# How can i add items to shopping cart using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am Beginner developer and i try to clone website (using HTML,CSS,JS)
and I stuck in Add products on shopping cart and these my Code:

```
const listProducts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Short Pant',
        price: '300.000 VND',
        imageUrl: 'img/1.jpg',
        button: 'Add to Cart'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Long Pant',
        price: '500.000 VND',
        imageUrl: 'img/2.jpg',
        button: 'Add to Cart'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Long Shirt',
        price: '400.000 VND',
        imageUrl: 'img/3.jpg',
        button: 'Add to Cart'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'T-Shirt',
        price: '200.000 VND',
        imageUrl: 'img/4.jpg',
        button: 'Add to Cart'
        
    }
];

const product = document.getElementsByClassName("product");

let item = "";
let listItem = item  => {
    for (i = 0; i < listProducts.length; i++) {
    item += `
    <div class="product-item">
      <img src="${listProducts[i].imageUrl}" alt="ảnh" />
      <h2>${listProducts[i].name}</h2>
      <div><span>${listProducts[i].price}</span></div>
      <button class="btn">${listProducts[i].button}</button></div>`
    }
    return item
}

product[0].innerHTML = listItem();

let btnCart = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
for (j = 0; j < listProducts.length; j++) {
    addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.document.querySelector('.listCart').append(item)
        
    })
```

And this is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      img {
        max-width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
        object-fit: contain;
      }
      .product {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      .product-item {
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
      }
      h2 {
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 50px;
        padding-top: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="product"></div>
    <div class="cart">
      <div class="listCart">
        <h2>Cart</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="bai10.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am Beginner developer and i try to clone website (using HTML,CSS,JS)
and I stuck in Add products on shopping cart and these my Code:
I am Beginner developer and i try to clone website (using HTML,CSS,JS)
and I stuck in Add products on shopping cart and these my Code:

I am Beginner developer and i try to clone website (using HTML,CSS,JS)
and I stuck in Add products on shopping cart and these my Code: